# SUMIF with multiple criteria using formula in the criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sample workbook for this problem can be found here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IkNv6outjKzwgvnG_7IPLpSt2vEAtcrq/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=117355411294900898171&rtpof=true&sd=true

I have a table in excel that looks like this.

[image]

What I want, is to create this table from the data.

[image]

If that's all I needed, then I could just use a pivot table, but for reasons unimportant here, that's not a possible solution.

I can use `SUMIF(Category, "Car", Amount)` to get the data for say all of cars, but this doesn't work with two variables.

Thus, I go to `SUMIFS(Table1[Amount], YEAR(Table1[Date]), 2021, Table1[Category], "Car")`, but this throws a "problem with this formula error" and won't accept it.  Btw, this doesn't work whether I use a cell reference or write in the criteria information.

Maybe there is an answer using SUMPRODUCT or arrays or something, but it's beyond me.

I found a solution that looks like this
`=SUMIFS(Table1[Amount], Table1[Category], "car", Table1[Date], ">=01/01/"&C22, Table1[Date], "<=12/31/"&C22)`.  Where C22 is the year "2022" or whatever and "car" could be replaced by a cell reference easily enough.  This works, but doesn't feel elegant.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Amount], (YEAR(Table1[Date])=2021)*(Table1[Category]="Car"))
```

Note with office 365 `SUMPRODUCT` can be just `SUM`

or use the SUMIFS as you show.

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Amount], Table1[Category], "car", Table1[Date], ">=01/01/"&C22, Table1[Date], "<=12/31/"&C22)
```

You could also use (with office 365):

```
=SUM(FILTER(Table1[Amount], (YEAR(Table1[Date])=2021)*(Table1[Category]="Car")))
```

But that is just a variation of the SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Welp, you made that easy.  I couldn't replace SUMPRODUCT with SUM, but SUMPRODUCT gave the right answer.  Will try the other solutions when I get a moment.  Thanks internet friend.